# Formatting with overlapping divs and bootstrap to form 2 columns

Tags: html, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make 2 nice columns of "Food Categories" populated with foods.

This is what I have so far. I cant figure out how to give the divs to go next to each other. I'm making my first rails app with bootstrap.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoruLdvs/1/)

Here is the template code I currently have for the page:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em;">
    0%
  </div>
</div>

<h3>List of all Categories</h3><br>

  <% @categories.each_with_index do |category, i| %>
      <div style=""<% if i % 2 == 0 %> class="col-md-offset-1" <% end %> <% if i % 2 == 1 %> class="col-md-offset-7" <% end %>>
      <h4><%= category.name %></h4>
      </div>

      <% category.foods.each do |food| %>
      <div style=""<% if i % 2 == 0 %> class="col-md-offset-2" <% end %> <% if i % 2 == 1 %> class="col-md-offset-8" <% end %>>
        <%= food.name %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>

<hr>
<%= button_to "Start Survey", survey_category_selection_path, class: "pull-right", method: :get %>
```

Comment: Can you add also the generated html ? It would help us the figure what is the problem. A JSFiddle would be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap each category in a div. Then, you put `.col-md-6` class. So each block will take 50% of the width.

You will have something like this

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em;">
    0%
  </div>
</div>

<h3>List of all Categories</h3><br>

  <% @categories.each_with_index do |category, i| %>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4><%= category.name %></h4>

      <% category.foods.each do |food| %>
      <div class="col-md-offset-1">
        <%= food.name %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<hr>
<%= button_to "Start Survey", survey_category_selection_path, class: "pull-right", method: :get %>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoruLdvs/3/)

Comment: I tried that and it still does not work. It looks like [picture](http://puu.sh/oiAE6/f33db224c5.png) now. I will keep trying to play with it... I see what you mean, I feel like I have to utilize inline-block somehow but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Like I said, can you give us the generated html ? Without it, it's hard to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: There are many files working together in my rails project, how would I go about doing this that is easy for you? Here is the [source](http://pastebin.com/6FgnGLxG) generated for the page.

Comment: @LukeCramer Thanks for the html. I have edited my answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I want but on my project it looks like [this](http://puu.sh/oiEo1/e960000c3d.png). Any idea why it is doing this? [HTML](http://pastebin.com/KhcgVE0a)

Comment: Figured it out - going to edit your comment so the code is correct. Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh, you're right, I forgot to move the `<div>` in the template. I'm glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you are asking is to align the div tags so that they appear side by side:

```
    div {
        width: 48%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

You may instead want to select .inline-block instead of div.
Please note that you need to keep the width less than 50% because your indentation will make the div tags not appear line.
Also, make a media query so that when the page gets smaller the div tags will appear as block, not inline block.

hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work, I think bootstrap makes the margins go all the way to the edge?